# xcode swift 4 Core Data relation between entities?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, entities

i am trying to make relation entity between 2 `entities` , unfortunately its not working well since i am still new with swift.

for example i have `playlist` table and `songs` table i want to make relation between them ?

[image]

and this is the Fetch Request :

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Playlist")

//        // Add Sort Descriptor
//        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "playlist_name", ascending: true)               
//        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


        let context = Appdelegate().managedObjectContext

        // Execute Fetch Request
        do {
            let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            print(result)
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
        }
```

can i create third table to make relation between songs and playlists like this ?

[image]

Comment: You have to define relationship. between two tables , lets say playList entity should have relationship (one to many) with songs

Comment: @dip i am still new with coredata can u please explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the relationship in the Core Data model editor. It's easier to use the model editor if you switch it to table mode using this control at the bottom of the window:

[image]

When you do that, the main part of the window will look something like this:

[image]

Click the "+" button in the relationships section to add a relationship. Fill in the destination entity and be sure to create an inverse relationship.

You should **not** create a third table to create the relationship. That's something you do in SQL but not in Core Data in most cases.

You may also want to review the [relationships section of Apple's Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1)

Comment: Thanks Tom for the good answer , but how i can query the relation ? without getting duplicate data. i am using swift 4

Comment: That’s a different question. You should post a new question asking about that.

Comment: my question including the fetch request too ! i don't know if u have notice this .